# My Website is giving 302 status code even after implementing 301 redirection code with .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, https, http-status-code-301, http-status-code-302

We have moved our site to https with implementing following code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^seekmi\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.seekmi.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]


# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress


## EXPIRES CACHING ##
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus
 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/font-woff "access plus 1 month"
#ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 7 days"
</IfModule> 
## EXPIRES CACHING ##

Options -Indexes
```

[By Tools I am getting 302 status code for all the urls](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NXZFq.png)

Can somebody help me figure out what is going wrong? Much appreciated if you can provide me correct code